# how to disable an ionic column using overlapping ionic-col or any other div

Tags: ionic3

I have a menu on the dashboard page like below:

[image]

I want to disable the menu buttons with an ion-col or any other div, same size as the col for the disable effect.

Comment: what do you mean by _with an ion-col or any other div_? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: want to display an ion-col with background grey and opacity 0.3 on top of this cart menu on some condition so that user cannot click on this cart menu(which is basically an ion-col)